# How can I call a command with non-value (InputOption::VALUE_NONE) param from other command?

Tags: symfony

If I execute from command line:
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n --em=views

everything work well.

However, when I try to execute this command from another command, I don't know how to put the InputOption::VALUE_NONE params into the ArrayInput.

```
private function executeMigrate($connection = null) {
    $theCommandStr = 'doctrine:migrations:migrate';
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find($theCommandStr) ;
    if ($command)
    {
        $arguments = [];
        $arguments['-n'] = null; //<-- THE PROBLEM IS HERE!
        $arguments['--em'] = 'views';

        $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

        if($returnCode == 0) {
            echo "OK";
        } else {
            echo "KO";
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested (without luck):
$arguments['-n'] = null;
$arguments['-n'] = "";

With the two options, the command was executed but the -n modifier was ignored.

I'm using Symfony v.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. If you want use --no-interaction or -n modifier in a command inside other command, you must use ArrayInput::setInteractive method:

Previous code would look like:

```
private function executeMigrate($connection = null) {
    $theCommandStr = 'doctrine:migrations:migrate';
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find($theCommandStr) ;
    if ($command)
    {
        $arguments = [];
        $arguments['--em'] = 'views';

        $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
        $input->setInteractive(false);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

        if($returnCode == 0) {
            echo "OK";
        } else {
            echo "KO";
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it won't work.